# why 0xc2000000>>24 == -62 in Java?

Tags: java, binary

`0xc2000000 = 1100 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.

So `0xc2000000 >> 24` should be `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 0010`,right?

But the result is `-62` which is `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110`.

I'm so confused

Comment: Have you used `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` to verify what the binary numbers actually are?

Comment: If you want the result to be `0xC2` aka `194`, then you need to use `>>>`, so it doesn't do sign-extension.